# Proof that infinite set of conservation laws imply no pair production

Tags: quantum-field-theory, conservation-laws, integrable-systems, pair-production, sine-gordon

In QFT in 1+1 dimensions it is known that the presence of an infinite number of conservation laws, specifically in integrable systems like Sine-Gordon, implies that there is no pair production, and then one can ignore this type of correction in calculating amplitudes. I cannot find a proof or argument for this statement so I would be very thankful if you can give one, let it be in Sine-Gordon specifically or in general.

Comment: A comment not an answer but how would factorised scattering fit in with pair production?

Comment: I'm not sure why a comment linking to [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9810026) was deleted (presumably by its author), but it seemed relevant.

Comment: thanks maybe the notes clarify the idea, I will read them

Answer (score 2):

Ref. 1 explains that if we consider $n$ massive 1-particle states of definite on-shell momenta in 1+1D, then the only interaction that generically preserves infinitely many, commuting conserved charges are 2-to-2 particle interactions, where initial and final momenta have the same magnitude; or compositions thereof. In particular, there is no particle production.

References:

1. Patrick Dorey, *Exact S-matrices* [arXiv:hep-th/9810026](https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9810026), p. 5-7.